# Prove that $x + y \ge (x^r + y^r)^{1/r}$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^+$ and $1 \le r \in \mathbb R$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

Recently, I have worked on the relationship of the norms $\ell_{p}$ and $\ell_{\infty}$. It leads me to prove the following inequality.

> $$x + y \ge (x^r + y^r)^{1/r}, \quad (x,y) \in {(\mathbb R^+)}^2, \quad 1 \le r \in \mathbb R$$

Could you please verify whether my attempt is fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

**PS:** I have not learned about derivative and its application yet.

---

**My attempt:**

It is easy to check that the above inequality is equivalent to

$$(x + 1)^r \ge (x^r + 1), \quad 1 \le x,r \in \mathbb R$$

For $1 \le r \in \mathbb R$, there exists a sequence $(r_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ that converges to $r$, and that $r_i \in \mathbb Q$ and $r_i \ge1$ for all $i$. As such, it suffices to prove that

$$(x + 1)^{m/n} \ge (x^{m/n} + 1), \quad 1 \le x \in \mathbb R, \quad m,n \in \mathbb N, \quad n \le m$$

Once again, it is easy to check that the above inequality is equivalent to

$$(x^n + 1)^m \ge (x^m + 1)^n, \quad 1 \le x \in \mathbb R, \quad m,n \in \mathbb N, \quad n \le m$$

We prove the last inequality by induction on $m$. It clearly holds for $m=n$. Assume that it holds for some $m \ge n$. Then $(x^n + 1)^m \ge (x^m + 1)^n$. We have

$$\begin{aligned}(x^n + 1)^{m+1} &= (x^n + 1)^m (x^n + 1) \\ &\ge (x^m + 1)^n (x^n + 1) \quad \text{by inductive hypothesis} \\ &= (x^{m+1} +x)^n + (x^m + 1)^n \\ & \ge (x^{m+1} +1)^n \quad \text{because}\ x \ge 1 \end{aligned}$$ 
This completes the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct but I suggest a simpler Calculus proof. $(x+1)^{r}-x^{r}$ is an increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ because its derivative is $r(x+1)^{r-1} -rx^{r-1}$ which is $\geq 0$. This function has the value $1$ when $x=0$. Hence $(x+1)^{r}-x^{r} \geq 1$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: I have not learned about derivative yet. Could you please verify my approach?

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as the site  allows to do so [I guess it is about 10 minutes ^^].

Comment: I think $$x + y \ge (x^r + y^r)^{1/r}, \quad (x,y) \in {(\mathbb R^+)}^2, \quad 1 \le r \in \mathbb R$$ is equivalent to $$(x + 1)^r \ge (x^r + 1), \quad 1 \le x,r \in \mathbb R$$.

Comment: You are right. I have deleted my previous comment.